# Troubleshooting SSL Error Max Retries in Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda, tls1.2

I am making a requests.post in aws lambda function to get some data from the web.

I am getting below error

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /host/endpoint (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1000)')))

I am using requests 2.31.0

Anybody knows what could be causing this? The same code works fine on my local machine.

My lambda isnt connected to a VPC (Attached screenshot) and I am requesting a https endpoint.

Any help is appreciated
Python version 3.12

[image]

Comment: Maybe the server blocks AWS ips